# Calculate$\operatorname{Var}(Y |X = 2)$ for a given pdf.

Tags: probability, statistics

> A machine has two components and fails when both components fail. The
>   number of years from now until the first component fails, X, and the
>   number of years from now until the machine fails, Y , are random
>   variables with joint density function
>   $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac1{18}e^{-(x+y)/6}&\text{if }0<x<y\\
> 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>   Calculate $\operatorname{Var}(Y |X = 2)$.

*My answer:* I can notice that the ftp is a product of two exponentials rv, with $\lambda= \frac16$. And the variance of an exponential is $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$. Then the variance of this pdf is $1/(1/6)^2=36$. Is that right? The book said it is $36$, but I'm not sure if my argument is correct.

*My question:* How to calculate $\operatorname{Var}(Y |X = 2)$?

Comment: In general case you will need find out the conditional pdf $Y|X=2$ from the given joint pdf. However in this case you just need to have a good observation, as what you did. But note that here $X, Y$ are ordered exponential rvs here; you can see the support of the joint distribution is not rectangular and they are not independent, and the normalizing constant is $\frac {2!} {6^2}$ to adjust for that. Luckily conditional on $X=2$, $Y$ is just become a shifted exponential, so the variance is the same as the ordinary exponential.

Comment: How can you say that it is product of marginal pdf's of exponential random variables since $\frac{1}{18}e^{-(x+y)/6}=\frac{1}{6}e^{-x/6}\frac{1}{3}e^{-y/6}$, where the marginals are not having mean as you have mentioned. Actually the two random variables are not independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don´t know if your argument is right. I have used the definition of the conditional variance.

$Var(Y|X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y^2\cdot h(y|x)\ dy- \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y\cdot h(y|x)\ dy\right] ^2$

$h(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$

$f_X(x)=\int_x^{\infty} \frac{1}{18}\cdot e^{-(x+y)/6} \ dy=\frac{1}{3}e^{-x/3}$

$h(y|x)=\frac{\frac{1}{18} e^{-(x+y)/6}}{\frac{1}{3}e^{-x/3}}=\frac{1}{6}e^{(x-y)/6}$

$h(y|2)=\frac{1}{6}e^{1/3-y/6}$

$\int_{2}^{\infty} y^2\cdot h(y|2) \ dy=\int_2^{\infty} y^2\cdot 1/6\cdot e^{1/3-y/6} \ dy=100$

$\int_{2}^{\infty} y\cdot h(y|2) \ dy=\int_2^{\infty} y \cdot 1/6\cdot e^{1/3-y/6} \ dy=8$

Answer (score 1):

You've observed that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\tfrac 1{18}\mathsf e^{-x/6}\mathsf e^{-y/6}$ is a product of two exponential *functions* and suggest this means it is the joint of two independent exponential *distributions*.

Let us test this.

$$\begin{align}f_X(x) & = \int_x^\infty \tfrac 1{18} \,\mathsf e^{-x/6}\,\mathsf e^{-y/6}\operatorname dy \;\mathbf 1_{0\le x}\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 3\mathsf e^{-x/3}\;\mathbf 1_{0\le x}\\[2ex] f_Y(y) & = \int_0^y \tfrac 1{18} \,\mathsf e^{-x/6}\,\mathsf e^{-y/6}\operatorname dx \;\mathbf 1_{0\le y}\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 3\left(\mathsf e^{-y/6}-\mathsf e^{-y/3}\right)\;\mathbf 1_{0\le y}\\[2ex] \therefore f_{X,Y}(x,y) \;& {\large\neq}\;f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y) & \color{red}{\mathcal X}\end{align}$$

So, nope.

---

However, your instincts were not *completely* off track.   Let $Z=Y-X$.

$$\begin{align}f_{X,Z}(x,z) & = f_{X,Y}(x,x+z)\\[1ex] & =\tfrac 1{18}\mathsf e^{-x/6}\mathsf e^{-(z+x)/6} \;\mathbf 1_{0\le x\le z+x}
\\[1ex] & =\tfrac 1{18}\mathsf e^{-x/3}\mathsf e^{-z/6} \;\mathbf 1_{0\le x}\,\mathbf 1_{0\le z}
\\[2ex]
f_X(x) & = \int_0^\infty \tfrac 1{18} \,\mathsf e^{-x/3}\,\mathsf e^{-z/6}\operatorname dz \;\mathbf 1_{0\le x}\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 3\mathsf e^{-x/3}\;\mathbf 1_{0\le x}\\[2ex] f_{Z}(z) & = \int_0^\infty \tfrac 1{18} \,\mathsf e^{-x/3}\,\mathsf e^{-z/6}\operatorname dx \;\mathbf 1_{0\le z}\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 6\mathsf e^{-z/6}\;\mathbf 1_{0\le z}\\[2ex] \therefore f_{X,Z}(x,z) \;& {\large = }\;f_X(x)\cdot f_{Z}(z)& \color{green}{\checkmark}\end{align}$$

So while $X,Y$ are not independent, the random variables $X, Z$ are, and further they have the exponential distributions you suspected.

Then $\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X=2) \\[1ex] = \mathsf {Var}(2+Z\mid X=2) \\[1ex] = \mathsf {Var}(Z)$

Now, as $Z\sim\mathcal{Exp}(1/6)$ you can find your variance.